# SUMO Simulation Error: Vehicle 'veh1' has no valid route. No connection between

Tags: python, xml, pycharm, sumo, network-traffic

I am trying to rn the SUMO simulation but it keeps saying there is an error on this :Error: Vehicle 'veh1' has no valid route. No connection between edge 'E8' and edge 'E9'.
Quitting (on error).

I attached my net.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- generated on 2024-02-26 00:13:04 by Eclipse SUMO netedit Version 1.19.0
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/neteditConfiguration.xsd">

    <input>
        <sumo-net-file value="C:\SUMO_\dell.net.xml"/>
    </input>

    <output>
        <output-file value="C:\SUMO_\dell.net.xml"/>
    </output>

    <processing>
        <geometry.min-radius.fix.railways value="false"/>
        <geometry.max-grade.fix value="false"/>
        <offset.disable-normalization value="true"/>
        <lefthand value="0"/>
    </processing>

    <junctions>
        <no-turnarounds value="true"/>
        <junctions.corner-detail value="5"/>
        <junctions.limit-turn-speed value="5.50"/>
        <rectangular-lane-cut value="0"/>
    </junctions>

    <pedestrian>
        <walkingareas value="0"/>
    </pedestrian>

</configuration>
-->

<net version="1.16" junctionCornerDetail="5" limitTurnSpeed="5.50" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/net_file.xsd">

    <location netOffset="0.00,0.00" convBoundary="-17.66,6.71,151.64,138.64" origBoundary="-10000000000.00,-10000000000.00,10000000000.00,10000000000.00" projParameter="!"/>

    <edge id=":J0_0" function="internal">
        <lane id=":J0_0_0" index="0" speed="6.62" length="8.96" shape="46.19,53.66 43.83,53.73 42.01,54.58 40.71,56.20 39.95,58.59"/>
        <lane id=":J0_0_1" index="1" speed="7.42" length="11.53" shape="46.19,53.66 42.44,53.55 39.63,54.25 37.75,55.74 36.80,58.03"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":J0_2" function="internal">
        <lane id=":J0_2_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="20.40" shape="46.19,53.66 40.21,52.92 36.00,52.29 31.83,51.48 25.94,50.19"/>
        <lane id=":J0_2_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="20.40" shape="46.57,50.48 40.64,49.75 36.54,49.14 32.47,48.35 26.63,47.07"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":J0_4" function="internal">
        <lane id=":J0_4_0" index="0" speed="9.10" length="17.51" shape="46.57,50.48 40.28,49.34 35.83,47.65 33.21,45.41 32.41,42.61"/>
        <lane id=":J0_4_1" index="1" speed="8.40" length="14.78" shape="46.57,50.48 41.68,49.49 38.22,47.88 36.20,45.62 35.61,42.74"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":J1_0" function="internal">
        <lane id=":J1_0_0" index="0" speed="6.51" length="8.81" shape="74.92,41.49 75.35,43.86 76.43,45.55 78.16,46.55 80.54,46.88"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":J1_1" function="internal">
        <lane id=":J1_1_0" index="0" speed="8.51" length="18.11" shape="71.73,41.61 71.20,46.74 69.19,50.21 65.68,52.02 60.68,52.16"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":J1_2" function="internal">
        <lane id=":J1_2_0" index="0" speed="6.65" length="8.81" shape="65.46,61.29 65.19,58.92 64.24,57.14 62.61,55.95 60.31,55.34"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":J1_3" function="internal">
        <lane id=":J1_3_0" index="0" speed="9.18" length="18.58" shape="68.66,61.37 69.51,56.45 71.77,52.93 75.45,50.81 80.55,50.08"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":J10_0" function="internal">
        <lane id=":J10_0_0" index="0" speed="6.75" length="5.86" shape="118.65,107.15 120.11,107.55 121.52,107.55 122.87,107.16 124.17,106.37"/>
        <lane id=":J10_0_1" index="1" speed="8.32" length="9.20" shape="117.46,110.12 119.76,110.75 121.97,110.75 124.10,110.13 126.14,108.89"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":J10_2" function="internal">
        <lane id=":J10_2_0" index="0" speed="6.91" length="13.11" shape="117.46,110.12 121.96,112.29 124.62,114.45 125.44,116.60 124.43,118.75"/>
        <lane id=":J10_2_1" index="1" speed="6.00" length="9.56" shape="117.46,110.12 120.62,111.68 122.44,113.28 122.92,114.92 122.05,116.60"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":J2_0" function="internal">
        <lane id=":J2_0_0" index="0" speed="6.63" length="9.37" shape="59.24,87.63 61.68,87.29 63.45,86.19 64.54,84.33 64.95,81.69"/>
        <lane id=":J2_0_1" index="1" speed="7.43" length="12.02" shape="59.24,87.63 63.08,87.32 65.85,86.24 67.54,84.39 68.15,81.77"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":J2_2" function="internal">
        <lane id=":J2_2_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="15.43" shape="59.24,87.63 64.00,87.59 67.31,87.58 70.51,88.10 74.95,89.63"/>
        <lane id=":J2_2_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="15.43" shape="59.19,90.83 63.60,90.78 66.67,90.74 69.64,91.19 73.76,92.60"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":J6_0" function="internal">
        <lane id=":J6_0_0" index="0" speed="6.79" length="2.38" shape="5.83,45.73 4.82,45.47 4.14,45.17 3.60,44.67 2.96,43.83"/>
        <lane id=":J6_0_1" index="1" speed="4.28" length="2.38" shape="6.52,42.61 6.19,42.52 5.96,42.42 5.78,42.25 5.57,41.97"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":J7_0" function="internal">
        <lane id=":J7_0_0" index="0" speed="3.90" length="2.89" shape="35.17,85.35 35.15,86.16 35.39,86.74 35.92,87.10 36.72,87.23"/>
        <lane id=":J7_0_1" index="1" speed="6.07" length="8.67" shape="32.02,84.79 31.94,87.22 32.69,88.97 34.26,90.04 36.66,90.43"/>
    </edge>

    <edge id="E0" from="J1" to="J0" priority="-1">
        <lane id="E0_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="14.21" shape="60.31,55.34 46.19,53.66"/>
        <lane id="E0_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="14.21" shape="60.68,52.16 46.57,50.48"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="E1" from="J2" to="J1" priority="-1">
        <lane id="E1_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="20.41" shape="64.95,81.69 65.46,61.29"/>
        <lane id="E1_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="20.41" shape="68.15,81.77 68.66,61.37"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="E10" from="J2" to="J10" priority="-1">
        <lane id="E10_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="47.07" shape="74.95,89.63 118.65,107.15"/>
        <lane id="E10_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="47.07" shape="73.76,92.60 117.46,110.12"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="E11" from="J10" to="J11" priority="-1">
        <lane id="E11_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="31.16" shape="124.43,118.75 103.53,141.86"/>
        <lane id="E11_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="31.16" shape="122.05,116.60 101.16,139.71"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="E12" from="J10" to="J12" priority="-1">
        <lane id="E12_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="31.08" shape="124.17,106.37 148.69,87.26"/>
        <lane id="E12_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="31.08" shape="126.14,108.89 150.66,89.79"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="E2" from="J3" to="J1" priority="-1">
        <lane id="E2_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="29.93" shape="73.82,11.58 74.92,41.49"/>
        <lane id="E2_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="29.93" shape="70.62,11.70 71.73,41.61"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="E3" from="J1" to="J4" priority="-1">
        <lane id="E3_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="46.46" shape="80.54,46.88 127.00,46.72"/>
        <lane id="E3_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="46.46" shape="80.55,50.08 127.01,49.92"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="E4" from="J4" to="J5" priority="-1">
        <lane id="E4_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="31.72" shape="128.59,45.11 128.40,13.39"/>
        <lane id="E4_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="31.72" shape="131.79,45.09 131.60,13.37"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="E5" from="J0" to="J6" priority="-1">
        <lane id="E5_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="20.60" shape="25.94,50.19 5.83,45.73"/>
        <lane id="E5_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="20.60" shape="26.63,47.07 6.52,42.61"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="E6" from="J0" to="J7" priority="-1">
        <lane id="E6_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="27.18" shape="39.95,58.59 35.17,85.35"/>
        <lane id="E6_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="27.18" shape="36.80,58.03 32.02,84.79"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="E7" from="J0" to="J8" priority="-1">
        <lane id="E7_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="31.66" shape="32.41,42.61 33.64,10.98"/>
        <lane id="E7_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="31.66" shape="35.61,42.74 36.83,11.10"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="E8" from="J6" to="J9" priority="-1">
        <lane id="E8_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="42.20" shape="2.96,43.83 -21.57,9.50"/>
        <lane id="E8_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="42.20" shape="5.57,41.97 -18.96,7.64"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="E9" from="J7" to="J2" priority="-1">
        <lane id="E9_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="22.53" shape="36.72,87.23 59.24,87.63"/>
        <lane id="E9_1" index="1" speed="13.89" length="22.53" shape="36.66,90.43 59.19,90.83"/>
    </edge>

    <junction id="J0" type="priority" x="37.01" y="47.73" incLanes="E0_0 E0_1" intLanes=":J0_0_0 :J0_0_1 :J0_2_0 :J0_2_1 :J0_4_0 :J0_4_1" shape="46.00,55.25 46.76,48.89 43.79,48.40 41.37,47.70 39.50,46.79 38.18,45.67 37.42,44.34 37.21,42.80 30.81,42.55 30.32,44.55 29.78,45.17 29.04,45.54 28.11,45.65 26.98,45.50 25.59,51.75 28.72,52.55 31.24,53.43 33.15,54.39 34.45,55.43 35.14,56.55 35.23,57.75 41.53,58.88 42.35,56.66 43.01,55.93 43.84,55.45 44.84,55.22">
        <request index="0" response="000000" foes="000000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="1" response="000000" foes="000000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="2" response="000000" foes="000000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="3" response="000000" foes="000000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="4" response="000000" foes="000000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="5" response="000000" foes="000000" cont="0"/>
    </junction>
    <junction id="J1" type="priority" x="70.50" y="51.72" incLanes="E2_0 E2_1 E1_0 E1_1" intLanes=":J1_0_0 :J1_1_0 :J1_2_0 :J1_3_0" shape="80.56,51.68 80.53,45.28 78.37,44.86 77.60,44.33 77.03,43.58 76.67,42.61 76.52,41.43 70.13,41.67 69.97,44.71 69.26,47.13 68.00,48.92 66.18,50.09 63.80,50.64 60.87,50.57 60.12,56.93 62.24,57.61 62.97,58.24 63.49,59.05 63.78,60.06 63.86,61.25 70.26,61.41 70.61,58.45 71.51,56.02 72.95,54.13 74.94,52.78 77.48,51.96">
        <request index="0" response="0000" foes="0000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="1" response="0000" foes="0000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="2" response="0000" foes="0000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="3" response="0000" foes="0000" cont="0"/>
    </junction>
    <junction id="J10" type="priority" x="122.41" y="113.83" incLanes="E10_0 E10_1" intLanes=":J10_0_0 :J10_0_1 :J10_2_0 :J10_2_1" shape="127.12,110.15 123.19,105.10 121.94,105.79 121.29,105.95 120.63,105.98 119.94,105.88 119.24,105.66 116.86,111.60 119.77,113.03 120.63,113.70 121.11,114.34 121.18,114.95 120.87,115.53 125.61,119.82 126.60,118.05 126.60,116.37 126.15,114.75 125.74,113.19 125.90,111.66">
        <request index="0" response="0000" foes="0000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="1" response="0000" foes="0000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="2" response="0000" foes="0000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="3" response="0000" foes="0000" cont="0"/>
    </junction>
    <junction id="J11" type="dead_end" x="99.97" y="138.64" incLanes="E11_0 E11_1" intLanes="" shape="104.72,142.93 99.97,138.64"/>
    <junction id="J12" type="dead_end" x="151.64" y="91.05" incLanes="E12_0 E12_1" intLanes="" shape="147.71,86.00 151.64,91.05"/>
    <junction id="J2" type="priority" x="69.48" y="92.61" incLanes="E9_0 E9_1" intLanes=":J2_0_0 :J2_0_1 :J2_2_0 :J2_2_1" shape="73.17,94.09 75.55,88.15 72.28,86.39 71.15,85.38 70.35,84.28 69.88,83.09 69.75,81.81 63.35,81.65 62.85,84.12 62.28,84.97 61.49,85.57 60.49,85.93 59.27,86.03 59.16,92.43 62.19,92.41 64.47,92.33 66.35,92.32 68.19,92.52 70.34,93.06">
        <request index="0" response="0000" foes="0000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="1" response="0000" foes="0000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="2" response="0000" foes="0000" cont="0"/>
        <request index="3" response="0000" foes="0000" cont="0"/>
    </junction>
    <junction id="J3" type="dead_end" x="69.02" y="11.76" incLanes="" intLanes="" shape="69.02,11.76 75.42,11.52"/>
    <junction id="J4" type="dead_end" x="133.43" y="51.50" incLanes="E3_0 E3_1" intLanes="" shape="133.39,45.08 126.99,45.12 127.01,51.52 130.57,50.80 131.82,49.90 132.70,48.65 133.22,47.04"/>
    <junction id="J5" type="dead_end" x="133.20" y="13.36" incLanes="E4_0 E4_1" intLanes="" shape="126.80,13.40 133.20,13.36"/>
    <junction id="J6" type="priority" x="6.87" y="41.04" incLanes="E5_0 E5_1" intLanes=":J6_0_0 :J6_0_1" shape="5.48,47.29 6.87,41.04 1.66,44.77 2.75,46.14 3.23,46.54 3.80,46.83 4.52,47.06">
        <request index="0" response="00" foes="00" cont="0"/>
        <request index="1" response="00" foes="00" cont="0"/>
    </junction>
    <junction id="J7" type="priority" x="29.13" y="91.90" incLanes="E6_0 E6_1" intLanes=":J7_0_0 :J7_0_1" shape="36.63,92.03 36.75,85.63 30.45,84.51 30.25,86.77 30.55,88.63 31.33,90.08 32.61,91.13 34.38,91.78">
        <request index="0" response="00" foes="00" cont="0"/>
        <request index="1" response="00" foes="00" cont="0"/>
    </junction>
    <junction id="J8" type="dead_end" x="38.43" y="11.16" incLanes="E7_0 E7_1" intLanes="" shape="32.04,10.91 38.43,11.16"/>
    <junction id="J9" type="dead_end" x="-17.66" y="6.71" incLanes="E8_0 E8_1" intLanes="" shape="-22.87,10.43 -17.66,6.71"/>

    <connection from="E0" to="E6" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":J0_0_0" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E0" to="E6" fromLane="0" toLane="1" via=":J0_0_1" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E0" to="E5" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":J0_2_0" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E0" to="E5" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":J0_2_1" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E0" to="E7" fromLane="1" toLane="0" via=":J0_4_0" dir="l" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E0" to="E7" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":J0_4_1" dir="l" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E1" to="E0" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":J1_2_0" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E1" to="E3" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":J1_3_0" dir="l" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E10" to="E12" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":J10_0_0" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E10" to="E12" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":J10_0_1" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E10" to="E11" fromLane="1" toLane="0" via=":J10_2_0" dir="l" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E10" to="E11" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":J10_2_1" dir="l" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E2" to="E3" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":J1_0_0" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E2" to="E0" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":J1_1_0" dir="l" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E5" to="E8" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":J6_0_0" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E5" to="E8" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":J6_0_1" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E6" to="E9" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":J7_0_0" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E6" to="E9" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":J7_0_1" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E9" to="E1" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":J2_0_0" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E9" to="E1" fromLane="0" toLane="1" via=":J2_0_1" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E9" to="E10" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":J2_2_0" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from="E9" to="E10" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":J2_2_1" dir="s" state="M"/>

    <connection from=":J0_0" to="E6" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J0_0" to="E6" fromLane="1" toLane="1" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J0_2" to="E5" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J0_2" to="E5" fromLane="1" toLane="1" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J0_4" to="E7" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="l" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J0_4" to="E7" fromLane="1" toLane="1" dir="l" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J1_0" to="E3" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J1_1" to="E0" fromLane="0" toLane="1" dir="l" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J1_2" to="E0" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J1_3" to="E3" fromLane="0" toLane="1" dir="l" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J10_0" to="E12" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J10_0" to="E12" fromLane="1" toLane="1" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J10_2" to="E11" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="l" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J10_2" to="E11" fromLane="1" toLane="1" dir="l" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J2_0" to="E1" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J2_0" to="E1" fromLane="1" toLane="1" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J2_2" to="E10" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J2_2" to="E10" fromLane="1" toLane="1" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J6_0" to="E8" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J6_0" to="E8" fromLane="1" toLane="1" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J7_0" to="E9" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="r" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":J7_0" to="E9" fromLane="1" toLane="1" dir="r" state="M"/>

</net>
```

and this is my rou file:I attached the screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaMVv.png)

Why is it not working?

I tried to ask GPT4 but it didn't work